# Jinja conditional concatenation for html attribute

Tags: logic, jinja2

I have the below jinja code to conditionally concatenate strings depending on two variables. Whilst it (probably) works it looks unwieldy, but I'd have thought this was a common thing to do when rendering.

```
{% if item.route %}
  {% if item.route_follow and item.route_external %}           {% set route_rel = 'external' %}
  {% elif not item.route_follow and not item.route_external %} {% set route_rel = 'nofollow' %}
  {% elif not item.route_follow and item.route_external %}     {% set route_rel = 'nofollow external' %}
  {% else %}                                                   {% set route_rel = '' %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a better way, maybe a one-liner?

Answer (score 0):

When I got to the end of this I realised the answer:

```
{% if item.route %}
  {% set route_rel = ['' if item.route_follow else 'nofollow', 'external' if item.route_external else '']|reject('==','')|join(' ') %}
{% endif %}
```

Sometimes, you just have to look at it again...